# BelongTo and pivot relationship query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

I have these tables

**Listings**

id

city_id

---

**Categories**

id

---

**Items**

id

category_id

---

Listings Table has **ManyToMany** Relationship with Categories Table, so there is another pivot table listing_category containing listing_id and category_id.

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Menu', 'listing_category', 'listing_id', 'category_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Items table has **BelongTo** Relationship with Categories Table.

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

Listings table has **hasOne** Relationship with cities table

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\City', 'id', 'city_id');
}
```

My goal is to build search with 2 inputs, users can search based on both **item name** and **city** (which is in listings table)

example, I want to search name of item  'item A' in city 'Los Angeles', the desired results list of items which located in 'Los Angeles' city.

How is the query to achieve this in laravel way?

The relationship table looks like this
[image]

Comment: So, is there a table of keywords, too?

Comment: no, there is no keywords table

Comment: How should items be matched against cities? I see no relation between those 2 models.